# How do I make non-value types nullable in C#?

Tags: c#, types, reference

For example:

```
public class Stereo {
   public Speaker? LeftSpeaker;
   public int? Volume;
}
```

The `int?` works fine, but I'm unable to make Speaker nullable. This is turning out to be surprisingly hard to Google, I thought this would be simple ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why would you want that? Non-value types (i.e. reference types) can already be set and compared to `null`.

Adding a `Nullable<T>` wrapper over reference-type objects would create *two* layers of nullability; pointless complexity, hence it is not allowed.

Comment: Half tempted to retag this question `duh`.

Comment: Well this could be why Googling "make reference types nullable" wasn't turning up anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is simple. "non-value" types are actually called references types in .NET and are automatically nullable. Just change your code thusly:

```
public class Stereo {
   public Speaker LeftSpeaker; // ? removed for ref type
   public int? Volume;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wild swag:

```
public class Stereo { 
   public Speaker LeftSpeaker; 
   public int? Volume; 

   public Stereo() {
       LeftSpeaker = null;   // Mission accomplished.
   }
}
```

Comment: @Noldorin: woops. missed some `()` didn't I?

Comment: Yeah, just though I'd fix it for you, since it was an obvious typo. :)

Comment: @Noldorin: No sweat. I've been mass-producing properties in dummy classes for the last couple of days, so my brain is just glossy :)

Comment: Yep, that would a cause! Easy mistake to make anyway, outside of a code editor.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of fish already here - but if you want to learn how to fish, I suggest having a look into [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s book [C# in Depth](http://csharpindepth.com/). Chapters 4.1 to 4.5 are dealing with all facets of the "concept of nullity" in C#.